# Storing queryset after fetching it once

Tags: python, django, web

I am new to django and web development.
I am building a website with a considerable size of database.
Large amount of data should be shown in many pages, and a lot of this data is repeated. I mean I need to show the same data in many pages.
Is it a good idea to make a query to the database asking for the data in every GET request? it takes many seconds to get the data every time I refresh the page or request another page that has the same data shown.
Is there a way to fetch the data once and store it somewhere and just display it in every page, and only refetch it when some updates are being done.
I thought about the session but I found that it is limited to 5MB which is small for my data.
Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/

Comment: I'll check it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/) - as mentionned by Leistungsabfall - can help, but like most cache systems it has some drawbacks too if you use it naively for this kind of problems (long queries/computations): when the cache expires, the next request will have to recompute the whole thing - which might take some times durring which *every* new request will trigger a recomputation... Also, proper cache invalidation can be really tricky.

Actually there's no one-size-fits-all answer to your question, the right solution is often a mix of different solutions (code optimisation, caching, denormalisation etc), based on your actual data, how often they change, how much visitors you have, how critical it is to have up-to-date data etc, but the very first steps would be to

- check the code fetching the data and find out if there are possible optimisations at this level using `QuerySet` features (`.select_related()` / `prefetch_related()`, `values()` and/or `values_list()`, annotations etc) to avoid issues like the "n+1 queries" problem, fetching whole records and building whole model instances when you only need a single field's value, doing computations at the Python level when they could be done at the database level etc
- check your db schema's indexes - well used indexes can vastly improve performances, badly used ones can vastly degrade performances...
- and of course use the right tools (db query logging, Python's profiler etc) to make sure you identify the real issues.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually the visitors number is limited because it is an internal website. but the up to date data is critical and I need to re-query the data every time and addition or deletion operation occurs.